# Book saga: the cover of each book had the main character on it, surrounded by circles or symbols on a plain blue background

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much, but the cover of each book had the main character surrounded by circles or symbols, and each book had the main character on the cover and the circles of the discovered characters were colored. The background was plain blue, dark blue but not like a deep blue.
One of the books, could be the third or the fourth, had on the cover a blonde girl, which I think was a magician or something, but I really don't remember much.

I think I read it about 15 years ago maybe, and in the first book they told the story of a boy, maybe discovering his powers? Unfortunately the only thing I remember is the cover and that he had to find more people like him (a person was added in each book).

Also it was just text, I read it in Spanish but don't know the original language. And the plot line definitely involve discovering the characters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us anything about the plot or characters? Also, in roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Was this just text? Illustrated? A comic book? Did the plotline involve discovering the characters or was it more of a meta "this is the party that we'll end up with" situation? Do you know what language it was originally in?

Comment: I think I read it about 15 years ago maybe, and in the first book they told the story of a boy, maybe discovering his powers? Unfortunately the only thing I remember is the cover and that he had to find more people like him (a person was added in each book)

Comment: Also it was just text, I read it in Spanish but don't know the original language. And the plot line definitely involve discovering the characters.

Answer (score 7):

This a bit of a stretch and I've read no more than the blurbs of the books, but potentially this is The Immortal Nicholas Flamel.

The books are all titled with different roles, and the description for.each one has the main characters (boy/girl twins) looking for someone to teach them more.

The covers are in a range of colours, but each have a circle motif and are unique to the book title/new character role.

[image: Covers]

They were published between 2007 and 2013 in Spanish as far as I can tell. So close to the 15 year mark.

Comment: This is what I thought of when I saw the title of the question as well.